# no Bounding Box

Tags: graphics, errors

Using TexMaker I am compiling with PDFLaTex the following and I get the error: ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Figures/chl.png (no Bounding Box).

```
\documentclass[draft,grl]{AGUTeX}
\usepackage[dvipdf]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{Figures/chl.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Drop the `draft` class option; drop the `dvipdf` option for [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx); (maybe also drop the `[H]` option to `figure`;) and compile using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Drop the `draft` class option. Keeping it will otherwise display images as black rectangles;
2. Drop the `dvipdf` option for [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). The package will find the appropriate driver. This *might* be the cause of your problem;
3. Not really an issue here, but you don't need the `figure` environment in order to include an image. I assume the option `[H]` is defined by your class (`AGUTeX`).